# Dynamically generate and resize TextViews depending on server response

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, textview

I'm trying to find the best possible way to generate the extviews between the two lines dynamically depending on the server response.
The range is from 1 to 9, So depending on that number , the Textviews need to be generated and resized to fill the content .
Example of 3

---

[ A-0002 ]

---

[ A-0002 ]

---

[ A-0002 ]

Note : The app will be run on an Android TV so the elements can't be scrolled and they need to be resized dynamically to fill the space

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add them programmatically inside LinearLayout with weighing 1 for each one for example

```kotlin
val layout = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.linear_layout)
val params = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, 1f)
val numberOfViews = 9
repeat(numberOfViews) {
    val text = TextView(this)
    text.text = "Text"
    text.layoutParams = params
    layout.addView(text)
}
```

You can also replace TextView with own custom view if needed